# vbcc compiler complains: file 'stdio.h' not found, but it is in the 'include' directory

Tags: compiler-errors, amiga

This is not a cross-compilation setup at the moment. Just a local C dev environment. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
 printf("Hello World\n");
}
```

I compile with command: *vbbcm68k test.c*

Output:

```
>#include <stdio.h>
error 248 in line 1 of "test.c": file 'stdio.h' not found
```

I've installed vbcc_bin_amigaos68k and vbcc_target_m68k-amigaos

My user-startup looks like this:

```
;BEGIN vbcc
assign >NIL: vbcc: Hard Disk:vbcc
assign >NIL: C: vbcc:bin vbcc:include ADD
setenv VBCC vbcc:
;END vbcc
```

My installation root looks like this ( the header files exist in include/ ):

```
Directories
bin
config
doc
include
lib

Files
test.asm
test.c
vbcc_inst.log
vbcc_version
```

If I copy the .h file to the root directory it works, but obviously I want them to be detected in vbcc:include. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Install from scratch

First of all, your install doesn't match the layout from the [distributed files](http://sun.hasenbraten.de/vbcc/). I suggest that you just wipe everything and then download and install (using the included installer scripts) in this order: [vbcc_bin_amigaos68k.lha](http://phoenix.owl.de/vbcc/2019-10-04/vbcc_bin_amigaos68k.lha) [vbcc_target_m68k-amigaos.lha](http://phoenix.owl.de/vbcc/2019-10-04/vbcc_target_m68k-amigaos.lha).

#### Or try to fix it

Neither *vc* nor *vbccm68k* looks automatically in `vbcc:include` for includes, you have to tell them where to look using the `-I` flag. If you use the *vc* command instead of the "raw" *vbccm68k*, it can pick up the include files from a script.

The default script for your platform is searched for at `ENV:vc.config`, `VBCC:vc.config`, or `$VBCC/config/vc.config` (from your *VBCC* environment variable). In your case it should be picked up from the environment, and you should have that file if you look in the *config* subdirectory.

If you examine `vc.config` you will see that it appends `-Ivincludeos3:` to the commands. The default installer sets up an assign to the (target-specific) include files, which should look something like this:

```
assign >NIL: vincludeos3: vbcc:targets/m68k-amigaos/include
```

In your case I guess it would be:

```
assign >NIL: vincludeos3: vbcc:include
```

Besides, this line is a little odd:

```
assign >NIL: C: vbcc:bin vbcc:include ADD
```

You should leave `vbcc:include` out of there, there are no binaries in the include directory.

#### Debugging

For debugging issues where a tool does not find its files, [SnoopDOS](https://aminet.net/package/util/moni/SnoopDos) is invaluable.

Comment: Thanks. The includes assign did not exist. I was also using vbccm68k instead of vc. Your solution worked.